# SAS:how to use macro in if-else statement

Tags: sas

when I merely used macro:

```
%extracTable();
```

there is no error..

however when I am using :

```
data _null_;

if 1=1

then %extracTable();

else put @@@do not insert@@@;

run;
```

it return :

```
error:unquote array:Execute

error:388-105

error 76-322

error:180-322
```

why and how to fix it...I am weak at sas Marco grammar..thank you

Comment: You will need to show the macro code.  The macro probably generates SAS code that causes the data step to end and subsequent generated code to be 'considered' by the SAS Supervisor in an out of context way.  Recommended reading is "A SAS® Programmer's View of the of the SAS Supervisor" Ian Whitlock, Westat Inc. (http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/ADVTUTOR/PAPER34.PDF)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite unlikely you want to use the same macro as a "standalone" script and inside data step if..then clause. If you want to execute the macro conditionally, try:

```
%macro extracTable();
%put some text;
%mend;

data _null_;
if 1=1 then call execute('%extracTable();');
else put '@@@do not insert@@@';
run;
```